# things are seldom quite as good as [in] clinical trials

Tags: phrase-meaning

Does the quote "things are seldom quite as good as [in] clinical trials" clearly point to Pfizer trial's performance in reality (that is, the author of the tweet critizes Pfizer vaccine as not as good as its trial showed - according to the quotation's point of view, Pfizer vaccine's question is par for the course)?

> The BMJ (British Medical Journal) Retweeted Elisabeth Mahase's tweete:

> Points on Israel vaccine reports:

- Real world data looked at people 60+ while trials incl younger people
- Israel did asymptomatic testing, Pfizer trial did not
- As Vallance said, "**things are seldom quite as good as [in] clinical trials**"

Comment: Saying *"things are seldom quite as good as [in] clinical trials"* ***implies*** that some contextually-relevant clinical trial data ***might*** be more "positive" than actual real-world data. But that's quite a long way from explicitly claiming that Pfizer vaccine as not as good as its trial showed. What was the question again?

Answer (score 0):

Vallance is making a general statement about the difference between clinical trials of a medicinal product and its performance in the marketplace post-approval. For a variety of reasons which are probably off-topic on this particular stack the performance is usually different and usually that means it is less good.

The tweeter is making the same point but in a stronger way about one specific example of the phenomenon.